# Trying to understand indexed types

Tags: fstar

I'm trying to understand the vector type from the FStar tutorial:

```
type vector (a: Type) : nat -> Type =
   | Nil :  vector a 0
   | Cons : hd: a -> n: nat -> tl: vector a n -> vector a (n + 1)
```

Constructing a vector - similarly to constructing ordinary lists - by `Cons nat 3 Nil` fails, while `Cons nat 3` is accepted. Could someone explain to me where I'm wrong by reading `Cons` as requiring a tail parameter? Furthermore, how vectors with actual elements are created - or is it an "empty vector" type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a bit of confusion here, sorry :)

1. The type argument `a` of `vector` is (for reasons that are also unclear to me) implicit for `Nil` and `Cons`. So when you write `Cons nat` the `nat` argument is really the `hd` argument and F* infers `a` to be `Type0` (the type of `nat`). So you're constructing a vector of types, which might not be what you intended.
2. The reason `Cons nat 3 Nil` fails is because the `3` argument is wrong and doesn't correspond to the length of the `Nil` list. `Cons nat 0 Nil` works and is the vector of size 1 containing the single type `nat`.
3. The reason `Cons nat 3` works is because you didn't yet give it the `tl` argument, so this is a partially applied constructor, `Cons` applied to 2 of its 3 arguments. The type of `Cons nat 3` is `vector Type0 3 -> vector Type0 4`, so a function that expects a vector of size 3 in order to produce a vector of type 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Catalin, thank you for your answer. It's very helpful and settles most of the confusion.